# Install Celery & Redis with Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, redis, celery

I use Django 1.9, Python 2.7 and Heroku.

Celery 3 & Redis were working well, until I switched to Celery 4.0.2 and changed the configuration.

heroku logs shows the following message:

```
2017-03-05T16:34:22.076383+00:00 app[worker.1]: Unknown command: 'celery'
```

Here are my configurations:

**__init.py__**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from .celery import app as celery_app
__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ... 
    'django_celery_beat',
)

if ENVIRONMENT == 'PROD':
    from settings_remote import *
else:
    from settings_local import *
```

**settings_remote.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals, absolute_import
import os
CELERY_BROKER_URL = os.environ['REDIS_URL']
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

**celery.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'terradiem.settings')
from django.conf import settings
app = Celery('terradiem')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

**Procfile**

```
web: gunicorn terradiem.wsgi --log-file -
worker: python manage.py celery worker --beat
```

**.env**

```
REDIS_URL=redis://
```

Any clue?

Comment: Have you attached redis into you app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Procfile, change:

```
worker: python manage.py celery worker --beat
```

for:

```
worker: celery -A [nameOfYourApp] worker --beat
```

and put the name of your django project in [nameOfYourApp].

It responds `Unknown command: 'celery'` because manage.py does not have a command name like that.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem yesterday with celery and spent hours trying to get rid of it. At the end, the problem was that I named my project's celery file **'celery.py'**.

So in my other files, when I referenced the celery library like so:

```
from celery import Celery
```

It was looking in my project's celery file for the Celery class and raising an error. Solution for me was to rename the file to _celery.py.

Also, check celery is installed on your server env.

I doubt this is your problem but had to suggest it!

Comment: I tried you suggestion but it does not seem to work. Thank you anyway.